# How to call a function on toggle of switch in a custom cell - TableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a switch button in a custom cell that is inserted into the tableView. How can I update the tableview on toggle of the switch button ?

Below is the function where I am inserting the custom tableViewCell that contains the toggleSwitch

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
  let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AvailabilityTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AvailabilityTableViewCell
            
  // Configure the cell...
  cell.availabilityLabel.text = "Available"
  switchIsOn = cell.availabilitySwitch.isOn
  return cell
            
 }
```

[image]

Comment: If you need to identify which cell toggled the `UISwitch` then add a `target/action` in your custom cell subclass and then use delegation to send a message to you view controller with your `cell` as a parameter. Also, why are you not using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)` in your `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UISwitch` is a subclass of `UIControl` which allows you to set a target/action on it:

Implement the following function in your `UIViewController`:

```swift
func toggled(sender: UISwitch) {
   // React to switch being toggled here
}
```

In your `cellForRowAt:` you can now the add the target/action to the cell's `UISwitch`:

```
cell.availabilitySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggled:), for: .valueChanged)
```